# Unable to define a class property with a type identical to the class (self-reference, like a hierarchy)

Tags: angular, typescript, class

I have an Angular model class with some properties self-referencing the class like so:

```
export class ItemCategory {
  constructor(
    public parentCategory?: ItemCategory, 
    public subCategories?: ItemCategory[], 
    public name?: string, 
    public description?: string
  ) { }
}
```

Angular compiler show me the following error:

```
ERROR in src/app/models/entities/itemCategory.model.ts(9,14): error TS2395: Individual declarations in merged declaration 'ItemCategory' must be all exported or all local.
src/app/models/entities/itemCategory.model.ts(28,10): error TS2395: Individual declarations in merged declaration 'ItemCategory' must be all exported or all local.
src/app/models/entities/itemCategory.model.ts(28,10): error TS2440: Import declaration conflicts with local declaration of 'ItemCategory'.
```

How can I self-reference the class?

**Edit: files using this class**

*src\app\models\services\itemCategory.service.ts*

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { ItemCategory } from "../entities/itemCategory.model";

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class ItemCategoryService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { } 

  public getAll() : Observable<ItemCategory[]> {
    return this.http.request<ItemCategory[]>("get", `api/ItemCategory`, { body: null });
  }

  public get(id: number) : Observable<ItemCategory> {
    return this.http.request<ItemCategory>("get", `api/ItemCategory/${id}`, { body: null });
  }

  public add(itemCategory: ItemCategory) : Observable<number> {
    return this.http.request<number>("post", `api/ItemCategory`, { body: itemCategory });
  }

  public update(id: number, itemCategory: ItemCategory) : Observable<number> {
    return this.http.request<number>("put", `api/ItemCategory/${id}`, { body: itemCategory});
  }

  public delete(id: number) : Observable<void> {
    return this.http.request<void>("delete", `api/ItemCategory/${id}`, { body: null });
  }
}
```

*src\app\models\repository.ts*

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { ItemCategory } from "./entities/itemCategory.model";

import { ItemCategoryService } from "./services/itemCategory.service";

@Injectable()
export class Repository {
  constructor(
    private itemCategoryService: ItemCategoryService
  ) {
      this.itemCategoryService.getAll().subscribe(response => this.itemCategories = response);
  }

  itemCategories: ItemCategory[];
}
```

Comment: Um, use `this`? Like `public parentCategory?: this`.

Comment: There is no error in this code, error is due to some other part, probably a public property with type that is not exported. Code compiles successfully https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=export%20class%20ItemCategory%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20constructor(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20parentCategory%3F%3A%20ItemCategory%2C%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20subCategories%3F%3A%20ItemCategory%5B%5D%2C%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20name%3F%3A%20string%2C%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20description%3F%3A%20string%0D%0A%20%20)%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D

Comment: @AkashKava is right. There is something else going on in your project

Comment: @Baruch, no, I get this error: `A 'this' type is available only in a non-static member of a class or interface` 
@AkashKava, well, if I replace the expected type by `any` it compile without any problem.

Comment: @Sébastien vare u able to compile your project by putting 'any ' public parentCategory?: any, 
    public subCategories?: Array<any>,  just to ensure self referencing causing problem

Comment: @NinjaJami, yes, that's right

Comment: @Sébastien are you importing this ItemCategory.ts file on the same file ? something like import { ItemCategory} from '../ItemCategory';

Comment: Please review what constitutes a [mcve] so that you can get a meaningful answer.

Comment: @NinjaJami, yes, this is the full class.

Comment: @Sébastien can u please check my answer ? just an assumption

Comment: Is this file imported anywhere in your project?

Comment: @ConnorsFan, yes, I updated my question to show the files using it.

Comment: Well, very strange: Visual Studio said I had a change in my file since my last commit but I couldn't figure out what it was (even in the diff tool). So I guessed it was a change in the file metadata or encoding and reverted the file to its previous state, tryed to compile again and the problem disapeared. Not even sure if I should answer this question as there is no evident added value for other people...

Answer (score 0):

I would assume you are declaring the class again along with import. As per my understanding I have reproduced the issue.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-error-reproduce?file=src/app/hello.component.ts

Something like below

```
//this also causing the issue //you don;t need import here
import { ItemCategory } from './ItemCategory';

export class ItemCategory {
  constructor(
    public parentCategory?: ItemCategory, 
    public subCategories?: ItemCategory[], 
    public name?: string, 
    public description?: string
  ) { }
}
```

In the below case you don't need to declare again.To use the class ,  just import and use wherever you want like below

```
import { ItemCategory } from './ItemCategory';
export class HelloComponent {
  @Input() name: string;

  sample : ItemCategory;
}
```

Comment: No, I do not import the class, the code I shown is exactly what I have in my `itemCategory.model.ts`.

Comment: @Sébastien can u please the entire file code , if that's not big enough. It will help to find easily the root cause. I hope you saw the scenarios i have  reproduced in my sample

Comment: Well, the only errors i can see in your samples are the useless imports, but I don't have them. Plus, it would still not compile if the only thing I change in the code is to set the `ItemCategory` type to `any`.

Comment: @Sébastien hmm.weird.. also as a part of trouble shooting you can create another set of class with different name and just check you are getting the same issue.